# FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS problem with line breaks

Tags: php, filter

Does anybody know how to prevent FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS from converting the line breaks ( \n ) into ( &#10 ; ).

I'm developing a simple commenting system for my website and I found that the php filter converts \n to 
 so when using nl2br() there are no line breaks.

help please.

thanks :)

Comment: Do you have some code which shows the newlines being converted into semi-colons?

Answer (score 15):

`filter_var` with the [`FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) option is doing what it is supposed to do:

> HTML-escape '"<>& and characters with
>   ASCII value less than 32, optionally
>   strip or encode other special
>   characters.

The newline character (`\n`) has an ASCII value of less than 32, so will be converted to `&#10;`.  You could therefore use [html_entity_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert them back to their original characters:

```
$string = "line 1\nline 2";
$filtered = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
echo "$filtered\n";
echo(html_entity_decode($filtered));
```

Outputs:

```
line 1&#10;line 2
line 1
line 2
```

But I guess that defeats the object of using `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` in the first place.

If it is only the newline that is causing the problem, you could replace the HTML character entity (`&#10;`) with a newline character, before using `nl2br()`:

```
echo str_replace('&#10;', "\n", $filtered);
```

Outputs:

```
line 1
line 2
```

Or perhaps even better, skip the middle step, and replace the HTML character entity (`&#10;`) with `<br />`:

```
echo str_replace('&#10;', '<br />', $filtered);
```

Outputs:

```
line 1<br />line 2
```

...but I'm not 100% sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you so much!
that works!
I really tried that before sending asking but it was the wrong way ;)
thanks a lot.